# How to check the methods of JS in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to analyze the methods of JS to study.
For example, there is a push() method.
And I want to see this push methods more concretly how to build for it.
I think that code would be in Nodejs.
https://github.com/nodejs/node
But I don't know where it is in some directory.
Could you recommend how to see the code?
Thank you so much for reading.

```
Array.prototype.push()
```

Comment: The code for Array is part of the Javascript implementation, not part of node.js itself.  Node uses the V8 implementation of Javascript (same one that the Chrome browser uses).  So, `Array.prototype.push` would be built into V8.  The V8 Javascript engine is itself open source so you could find that code if you really wanted to.  It will have to do with the internal memory implemenatation of arrays in V8 which can be fairly complicated since there are multiple types of ways that arrays can be stored depending upon whether they are sparse or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to know a little more about how to use this method, with some examples and good practices, some places to start are the Mozilla Developer Doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push and Javascript Info Doc https://javascript.info/array

You can always look in the official specs, https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.push. Remember to be careful to look the correct version.

To try something more complex, high-performance stuff, take a look in the Buffers and Typed Arrays of the Node.JS Doc https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/buffer.html, HTML5 Rocks https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/ and again Mozilla Developer Doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray and the Offical ECMA https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typedarray-objects.

If you really are trying to look under the hood of how the node works (the C code of it), then https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/js_native_api.h#L61 maybe is a good place to start.